# How to create a validation rule to deny all users creating new records except one

Tags: validation-rule, roll-up-summary, record-owner

I have a roll-up summary filed which is calculating the number of child records.

If the number of child records is greater than 2 I need to deny all users from creating new records except one.

I need to allow only one user / record owner to be able to create a third record.

I've created the following validation rule:

```
my_custom_rollup_field > 2 && $ObjectType.Child_Custom_Object__c.Fields.Owner__c <> 'owner.Id'
```

However that validation rule is not working.

Please advise what else I need in my validation rule to give the opportunity to only one user / record owner to be able to create a third record?
​​​​​​​

Comment: Can you post your actual validation rule? IT is hard to troubleshoot a formula in abstract.  The validation rule is checking on the parent fields, right?  So the formula should be something like ParentObj__r.RollupField__c > 2 && $User.Id <> ParentObj.OwnerId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this validation rule.

```
 ISNEW() && (my_custom_rollup_field > 2 || OwnerId <> $User.Id)
```

Comment: You forgot isnew. Otherwise others will not be able to edit if a 3rd is present

Comment: @Eric for new records, how it is possible to have child records and rollup.

Comment: It’s not which is why this validation rule will not work.  If the user adds a 3rd then after that no other user will be able to edit the parent since the roll up will be > 2. Was trying to get you to see that

Comment: Yeah! Got it and updated as well.

Comment: But isnew does not help either. As it will not block

Comment: @Eric
I don't think Validation rule should be used on rollup summary, According to SF docs `Calculating roll-up summary field values may take up to 30 minutes, depending on the number of records affected and other factors.`

Comment: My main point here is I do not think this should/can be done with a validation rule  on the parent at all. Unless the op changes criteria to cannot create or edit parent or child. Of course I could’ve be wrong. It’s early and no coffee yet

Comment: @Reshma, using your validation, now all of the users can create a third record. That is what I strive to avoid. I have the validation rule created on my parent object. That is why I'm using `$ObjectType.Child_Custom_Object__c.Fields.Owner__c`. But that is not working either. Could you please advise what else I can try to make my validation rule work?